# PHP preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

```
preg_replace("/{{(.*?)}}/e","$$1",$rcontent);
```

Please explain the statement to me...i cant understand this

Comment: Why vote to close this? It's pretty clear that the question is asking what the regex means.

Comment: @Alex JL: I did not vote to close, but it must have been the title. I don't know what meta tags have to do with the question.

Comment: @BoltClock it is pretty mysterious.

Answer (score 4):

Consider an example use:

```
$rcontent = "abc {{foo}} def";
$foo = 'bar';
$rcontent = preg_replace("/{{(.*?)}}/e","$$1",$rcontent); 
echo $rcontent; // prints abc bar def
```

I'm assuming that you are assigning the value of `preg_match` back to `$rcontent` or else it will not make any sense.

Now the regex you are using is `{{(.*?)}}` which looks for anything (non-greedyly) between `{{` and `}}` and also remembers the matched string because of the parenthesis.
In my case the `.*?` matches `foo`.

Next the replacement part is `$$1`. Now `$1` is `foo`, so `$$1` will be `$foo` which is `bar`. So the `{{foo}}` will be replaced by value of `$foo` which is `bar`.

If the `$$1` is just a type and you meant to use `$1` then the regex replaces `{{foo}}` with `foo`.

Comment: $file=file("templates/index.html");
$rcontent=join("",$file);
$rcontent=preg_replace("/{{(.*?)}}/e","$$1",$rcontent);
print $rcontent;
this is my code.its working perfectly..but templates/index.html file  doesn't have any paranthesis in it..

Comment: @sowmiya: Sorry I did not get your question.

Comment: am copying the content of "templates/index.html" to a php file....To copy the content am using this regex.. i don't have any curly braces in my "templates/index.html" file.. but it works perfectly..how this template engine works i dunno...

Answer (score 0):

lazy *
Repeats the previous item zero or more times. Lazy, so the engine first attempts to skip the previous item, before trying permutations with ever increasing matches of the preceding item.

for eg: `.*?` matches `"def"` in `abc "def" "ghi" jkl`

http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html